# How can I play a bot with expansion cards in Dominion Online?

Tags: dominion

[Dominion Online](https://dominion.games/) noob here. I'm trying to play a bot with expansion cards, but it seems to only allow me to select base cards.

I've added familiar cards by adding expansions I own, but can't seem to select any of them.

I wondered if this was even possible, but I spectated a game in which a user was playing a bot with expansion cards, so it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to **purchase** a subscription to the expansion sets. While the base-game cards are free, the expansion cards are not. After you log in, go to the **Store** tab and you shall find two different types of subscriptions available:

1. *Silver*, which includes the following sets: Intrigue, Seaside, Prosperity, Cornucopia, Hinterlands, Guilds
2. *Gold*, which includes all sets from the *Silver* subscription, plus Alchemy, Dark Ages, Adventures, Empires

These are per-day subscriptions, not permanent purchases, but you can define the expiry day of your subscription; e.g., if you would like to test the expansions, you can even subscribe for a day or week. Note that there is a transaction fee to be paid as well (0.35 EUR, as of 2017-04-08).

Note that you need to purchase the expansions to **open a new table** on your own. This, naturally, includes playing alone against a bot. Nevertheless, you can always join for free any table, even with expansion cards, as long as the table administrator has paid for them.